# Getting variable no of pandas rows w.r.t. a dictionary lookup

Tags: pandas

In this sample dataframe df:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random, string

max_rows = {'A': 3, 'B': 2, 'D': 4} # max number of rows to be extracted

data_size = 1000

df = pd.DataFrame({'symbol': pd.Series(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for _ in range(data_size)),
              'qty': np.random.randn(data_size)}).sort_values('symbol')
```

How to get a dataframe with variable rows from a dictionary?

Tried using `[df.groupby('symbol').head(i) for i in df.symbol.map(max_rows)]`. It gives a RuntimeWarning and looks very incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `concat` with list comprehension:

```
print (pd.concat([df.loc[df["symbol"].eq(k)].head(v) for k,v in max_rows.items()]))

    symbol       qty
640      A -0.725947
22       A -1.361063
190      A -0.596261
451      B -0.992223
489      B -2.014979
593      D  1.581863
600      D -2.162044
793      D -1.162758
738      D  0.345683
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding another method using `groupby+cumcount` and `df.query`

```
df.assign(v=df.groupby("symbol").cumcount()+1,k=df['symbol'].map(max_rows)).query("v<=k")
```

Or same logic without assigning extra columns `#thanks @jezrael`

```
df[df.groupby("symbol").cumcount()+1 <= df['symbol'].map(max_rows)]
```

---

```
    symbol       qty
882      A -0.249236
27       A  0.625584
122      A -1.154539
229      B -1.269212
55       B  1.403455
457      D -2.592831
449      D -0.433731
634      D  0.099493
734      D -1.551012
```